# looping through blade produces duplicates on alpine x-model array property

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

#### Description:

when using alpine x-model with livewire it is appending duplicate value to alpine array when checked.

#### Implementation:

Here is a render method from component class:

```php
protected $dueCommissions;

public function loadDueReward()
{
  //paginated query for $this->dueCommissions
}
public function render()
{
  //passing dueCommissions here, due to livewire limitation of handling paginated data
  return view('reward::livewire.due-reward', [
  'dueCommissions' => $this->dueCommissions
  ]);
}
```

```php
<div class="main-content" wire:init='loadDueReward' wire:target='loadDueReward;gotoPage' x-data="{
    selectedUsers: []
}">
  @foreach ($dueCommissions ?? [] as $dueCommission)
    <tr wire:key='due-user-{{ $dueCommission->id }}'>
      <td class="table-cell-first">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" name="user" value="{{ $dueCommission->user_id }}" x-model="selectedUsers">
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

This code produce duplicates in the alpine selectedUsers when clicked:
[image: duplicates]

#### Context

- Livewire version: "livewire/livewire": "^2.10"
- Laravel version: "laravel/framework": "^9.0"
- alpinejs@3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mount()` f-n instead of `wire:init`. Maybe x-model doesn't like, when DOM is updated after Alpine component.

If that doesn't help, then I would check data types, because `$dueCommission->user_id` `14741` !== `'14741'`

Comment: I don't think this is happening because of data types. Using mount can be a solution but that won't help in this scenario, I want to render the ui, when data is ready with no loading time to render initial ui